# Исключение обязательная типизация переменной, если задано через as

Tags: typescript

Всем привет.
Ребят, кто может подсказать: Использую правило `variableDeclaration` .

```
"@typescript-eslint/typedef": [
  "error",
  {
    "variableDeclaration": true,
    "variableDeclarationIgnoreFunction": true
  }
]
```

Есть ли правило, что бы, если было типизировано через `as`, то ошибку НЕ выдавало. Так:

```
const $target = e.target as HTMLElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо выставить занчения `false` в файле линтера для следующих:

```
//tslint.json
...
"rules": {
    "no-unnecessary-type-assertion": true, -> false
    "no-object-literal-type-assertion": true, -> false
    "no-angle-bracket-type-assertion": true, -> false
}
...
```

Comment: не помогло... всё также просит типизировать